# How to thicken Paint

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

I'm non technical and have a question that you can hopefully help me out with as I've been searching online and so far haven't found any answered

I'm looking for a product that will thicken the following paint

[polymarineshop - hypalon paint for avon inflatables](https://www.polymarineshop.com/product/hypalon-paint-for-avon-inflatables/)

Any help at all would be greatly received

Best wishes

Ant

Comment: Is it thinner than it should be ? ( e.g. after using a thinner solvent). Or do you just want it thicker for whatever reasons ? Any thickering may negatively impact the paint properties. I advice rather asking the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Diisocyanates are used in some coatings and polymerize in contact with moisture. Flexithane contains a non-reactive polyurethane (already reacted diisocyanate), and so is simply a solution of rubber in a mixture of solvents (SDS: http://www.hmgcoatings.co.uk/msdspdfs/Flexithane.pdf).

The literature claims dry to touch in 5 minutes, ready for a second coat in 20 minutes at 20C. One way to thicken the paint without adding anything that would destroy its performance would be to evaporate some of the solvent. In a can about half-filled with the paint, stir well, with plenty of ventilation (as advised by the SDS) for a few minutes. At £49.66 to £75 per 500 mL, it could be be an expensive experiment if you don't stir well enough and you get lumps or skin in the paint when you try to apply it.